# Display columns for 4 employee have job id like SA_MAN and have salary >10000

Tags: oracle, loops, for-loop, plsql

I want to display: employee id, employee name, job id, salary, for 4 employee have job id like SA_MAN and have salary >10000 using loop statements I wrote this code but I get an error

What's wrong with this code?

```
DECLARE
  emp_name employees.last_name%type;
  emp_id employees.employee_id%type;
  sal employees.salary%type;
  jobid employees.job_id%type;

BEGIN
  SELECT employee_id,
    last_name,
    job_id,
    salary
  INTO emp_id,
    emp_name,
    jobid,
    sal
  FROM employees
  WHERE salary>10000
  AND job_id LIKE'%SA\_%N' ESCAPE'\';

FOR i 1..3 dpms_output.put_line(emp_id||' '||emp_name||' '||jobid||' '||sal);
END LOOP;

END;
```

This is the error I get:

```
Error starting at line 1 in command:
DECLARE
  emp_name employees.last_name%type;
  emp_id employees.employee_id%type;
  sal employees.salary%type;
  jobid employees.job_id%type;

BEGIN
  SELECT employee_id,
    last_name,
    job_id,
    salary
  INTO emp_id,
    emp_name,
    jobid,
    sal
  FROM employees
  WHERE salary>10000
  AND job_id LIKE'%SA\_%N' ESCAPE'\';

FOR i 1..3 dpms_output.put_line(emp_id||' '||emp_name||' '||jobid||' '||sal);
END LOOP;

END;
Error report:
ORA-06550: line 20, column 7:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "1" when expecting one of the following:

   in
06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
*Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
*Action:
```

Comment: ....and what's the error you get?

Comment: At least `LOOP`behind `1..3` is missing.

Comment: `IN` before `1..3` is missing: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/controlstructures.htm#CJAIJFCI

Comment: @Toru  what you mean , what should i do

Comment: @BurhanKhalid  i put the error

Comment: You should read the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/controlstructures.htm#CJAIJFCI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved by doing the following:

```
begin
  for i in ( SELECT employee_id, last_name, job_id, salary
               FROM employees
              WHERE salary > 10000
                AND job_id LIKE '%SA\_%N' ESCAPE '\' ) LOOP

     dbms_output.put_line( i.employee_id || ' '
                         || i.last_name || ' '
                         || i.job_id || ' '
                         || i.salary );

   end loop;
end;
```

You don't need to do this though. You can just SELECT what you want. More generally, please pay attention to your spacing, it makes your code a lot more readable.

---

The actual errors are as follows:

1. If you're performing a FOR LOOP you need an IN and a LOOP

   `FOR i 1..3` should be `for i in 1 .. 3 loop`
2. `dbms_output` is spelt as I have done, not `dpms_output`.
3. You're selecting multiple rows into a type defined as a single row. This will raise the [TOO_MANY_ROWS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/errors.htm#LNPLS00703) exception. Equally, if this query returned 0 rows a NO_DATA_FOUND exception will be raised.

---

If you want to select everything and then loop through the values you could use a [BULK COLLECT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/tuning.htm#LNPLS891). It's overkill though for this situation. Note that I don't assume the number of values that the query is going to return.

```
declare

   cursor c_emp is
    select employee_id, last_name, job_id, salary
      from employees
     where salary > 10000
       and job_id like '%SA\_%N' ESCAPE '\';

   type t__emp is table of c_emp%rowtype index by binary_integer;
   t_emp t__emp;

begin

   open c_emp;
   fetch c_emp bulk collect into t_emp;
   close c_emp;

   for i in t_emp.first .. t_emp.last loop
     dbms_output.put_line( i.employee_id || ' '
                         || i.last_name || ' '
                         || i.job_id || ' '
                         || i.salary );
   end loop;

end;
/
```

Apologies for the syntax highlighting. There's a bug with Google Prettify on escaped single quotes in the SQL markdown.

Comment: now its work but its not appear in the output i write set serveroutput on

Comment: Does the SELECT statement return any rows? Maybe you've got nobody with a high enough salary in your table?

Comment: no i check it before, its contain 5 employees with this job and this salary but the problem i don't but this values from select into variable i have declared in declare section